# Is it possible to set Cookie Session ID from a REST Service?

Tags: sessions

I have overridden Drupal's login process by calling a REST API which returns a 'true' or a 'false' depending on whether the login was successful or not. Once successful, I'm logging the user in by using a particular Drupal user account.

Would it be possible to change Drupal's Session ID to the one specified by the REST API call? Currently the REST API Call is giving me a JSESSIONID cookie and I was wondering if its possible to map this cookie to the one Drupal generates when the user logs in. Reason I need this is because I need keep track of this JSESSIONID to call other API methods related to the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You cant save off the `JSESSIONID` into the user attributes, eg `data` column, in D6 or D7. You simply do this in your code with:

```
$_SESSION['JSESSIONID'] = /* some value here */;
```

or wherever you call [user_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) in your custom login you can pass `$edit['data'] = array('jsessionid' => 12341234);` from the user_save documentation:

> $edit: An array of fields and values to save. For example array('name'
>   => 'My name'). Key / value pairs added to the $edit['data'] will be serialized and saved in the {users.data} column.

it then becomes accessible from a fully loaded `$user` object as simply a field of the user ... `$jsessionid = $user->jsessionid;` and you can use it as needed.

Comment: \Drupal::service('session')->setId($jsessionid); Should also work.
\Drupal::service('session')->getId(); to get the id.